# pruning tree search in multiplayer zero-sum games with loss conditions

Tags: artificial-intelligence, games

I'm trying to write a program to play a simple multiplayer (it's safe to assume less than 10 players) game where each player has a number of resources.
Every turn the players make decisions that affect both their resources and the resources of their opponents.
For the purposes of a mini-max tree search, the evaluation function simply returns the number of resources a player has.

To effectively prune nodes there needs to be a bound on each player's score.
We can subtract the opponent's resources divided by the number of opponents, the total score of all players will add up to 0:
`(player score) = (player resources) - (opponent resources) / (number of opponents)`
This also nicely represents the fact that it's better if opponents have fewer resources.
With this new bound in place, some nodes can be pruned similar to 2-player alpha-beta-pruning.

A problem arises when we add another rule, if any player reaches 0 resources they are eliminated from the game.
The last player to be eliminated wins.
I thought of a few ways to handle this case so I'll describe the problems I'm facing for each of them.

1. Decrease the number of opponents, eliminated players internally have a 0 score.
   This does not work because player score can be negative while still playing, they might intentionally try to eliminate themselves to reach a higher, 0, score.
2. Fixed number of opponents, eliminated player's scores are calculated as normal.
   Does not work because players are unable to make decisions after they are eliminated, their score can descend to negative infinity while the other player's scores have no bound so no pruning will happen.
3. Fixed number of opponents, eliminated player's scores are set to a fixed very negative value.
   Does not work because other player's scores will necessarily have to rise to keep the game zero-sum, a player might give up a lot to eliminate a single opponent which is not worth it.

The score and pruning functions work fine without any loss condition.
Adding a loss condition either breaks the score function, and thus the program's behavior, or it breaks the pruning strategy making the program unbearably slow.

I've read some papers on pruning in n-player games but none of them tackle loss conditions.
I'm not sure why there shouldn't be a way to make this work, but I can't think of a way to make it work either.
What pruning/evaluation strategy can I use that will keep the behavior sane and the performance reasonable?

PS: not sure if this is the correct place for these kinds of questions, if not please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Nat I've updated my answer to hopefully be more clear. I'll also answer some of your questions here. "I get the sense that you're coming from a very focused context" Not really, I ran into this problem with multiple of my AI projects and came up with this example for the question. "what's the tree represent?" A typical game tree, every node is a game state and every edge is a move. "And what conditions are causing its pruning to be computationally significant?" When a player is eliminated, either the bound is violated or the scores become inconsistent and the bot makes bad decisions.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still not quite getting it.  There's [an SE specifically for game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), so they might be aware of the context.  The problem for me is that I'm not sure how the things referenced in the question fit together.  I'm guessing that your game is essentially in a loop that keeps repeating an evaluation of the tree, where the tree is the main data-structure that grows as players make moves, storing a history of all game interactions.  And then I guess you want to.. remove players from history, if they're defeated? [...]

Comment: @Nat I think you entirely misunderstood the scope of my question. My question is about implementing a program to play a game (artificial intelligence), not about implementing the game itself. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning